# relay email using postfix

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I'm in over my head, and became in charge of a Linux server that runs a tomcat application.  The application currently is configured to send email directly to a postfix relay server.  I was asked if it would be possible to set up Postfix locally on the server and have the app send mail to it, and then have Postfix deliver to the mail relay server.  I said "sure!", but now I'm not sure how to do this.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  I'm not sure what the terminology I need to search for is.  If the mail relay server is down, will the local Postfix instance queue the mail until it can be delivered?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

what you need is to specify the relayhost parameter in main.cf (usually /etc/postmaster/main.cf):

relayhost = [relayserver]

after editing the file, reload postfix:

```
# postfix reload [enter]
```